How much spacing is required or recommended between bundles of cable?
I'm considering a house rewiring project due to old insulation and much changed code. Looking at 2008 NEC table 310.15(B)(2)(a), the previous paragraph says "Where the number of current-carrying conductors in a raceway or cable exceeds three, or where single conductors or multiconductor cables are installed without maintaining spacing for a continuous length longer than 600mm (24in.) and are not installed in raceways, the allowable ampacity of each conductor shall be reduced as shown in Table 310.15(B)(2)(a). Each current-carrying conductor of a paralleled set of conductors shall be counted as a current-carrying conductor."
My questions therefore are:
(1) What is the code required or otherwise recommended distance between bundles of Romex/NM cable? I know there are code requirements for spacing with communications, but I did not find any specific recommendations for cable bundles. Multiple Loose-Hanging Wires in Finished Wall is relevant but not the same, I think.
(1a) I can have the cables loose between joists if that helps, but is that the same as spacing?
(1b) See NEC Definition of "Maintained Spacing" for Wire in Free Air -- is loose really sufficient or do I need to somehow hold the spacing with a comb like in PC cable management?
(1c) So for instance, if I had 4 12-2 NM cables in the same set of joist holes but otherwise loose, will that derate the cables according to Table 310.15?

Not quite sure, but bundles are like zip tieing a bunch of romex cables together.  I think as long as cable as some air between it and the next, between the joist holes it is okay.  Stuffing the holes with as many cables that can be stuff in is not okay.  Can usually make a second hole to spread them out.

There are conduit fill tables that will let you know how many wires that can fit in a conduit of a certain diameter.

crip659 -- thanks for the comments. I know there's conduit fill tables for specific types of conduit, I was looking at the one for PVC conduit earlier, but is there one tor holes in a joist? I'd guess that the "longer than 600mm" part comes into play so that you really can cram a joist hole full of conductors.

Also, I'm not sure if letting the wires dangle constitutes a bundle; they certainly do tend to sag together going from support to support, so seems like it would have similar heat issues without some sort of cable comb.

First of all there is usually never a big amp draw on a residential cable to cause heating of conductors. If you drill a hole in a stud no more than the
three 120v cables should run through it. Keep the 240 v cables separate , one cable per hole. Cables laying across rafter in an attic can be close to each other, leave a little space. Bundling is when many cables are tie wrapped together, of taped. That's the heating up of cable concern. Nothing to loose sleep over!

I like them a lot , great option. Just be careful with drilled holes in the studs and the double plate above the circuit breaker panel .
